# XNA, how do I know what key is being pressed?

Tags: c#, xna

SKIP TO EDIT 3:
I plan to make use of this that I found online. However, I can't figure out how the proper variable that works for its parameter of `Keys key`. I can't figure out what type of variable I have to send to the procedure. I tried sending my `Keyboard kbState = Keyboard.GetState()` but it didn't work. I tried sending `kbState.GetPressedKeys()` but it said it wouldn't work. How do I do it?

```
public static string ConvertKeyToChar(Keys key, bool shift) 
{ 
    switch (key) 
    { 
        case Keys.Space: return " "; 

        // Escape Sequences 
        case Keys.Enter: return "\n";     // Create a new line 
        case Keys.Tab: return "\t";       // Tab to the right 

        // D-Numerics (strip above the alphabet) 
        case Keys.D0: return shift ? ")" : "0"; 
        case Keys.D1: return shift ? "!" : "1"; 
        case Keys.D2: return shift ? "@" : "2"; 
        case Keys.D3: return shift ? "#" : "3"; 
        case Keys.D4: return shift ? "$" : "4"; 
        case Keys.D5: return shift ? "%" : "5"; 
        case Keys.D6: return shift ? "^" : "6"; 
        case Keys.D7: return shift ? "&" : "7"; 
        case Keys.D8: return shift ? "*" : "8"; 
        case Keys.D9: return shift ? "(" : "9"; 

        // Numpad 
        case Keys.NumPad0: return "0"; 
        case Keys.NumPad1: return "1"; 
        case Keys.NumPad2: return "2"; 
        case Keys.NumPad3: return "3"; 
        case Keys.NumPad4: return "4"; 
        case Keys.NumPad5: return "5"; 
        case Keys.NumPad6: return "6"; 
        case Keys.NumPad7: return "7"; 
        case Keys.NumPad8: return "8"; 
        case Keys.NumPad9: return "9"; 
        case Keys.Add: return "+"; 
        case Keys.Subtract: return "-"; 
        case Keys.Multiply: return "*"; 
        case Keys.Divide: return "/"; 
        case Keys.Decimal: return "."; 

        // Alphabet 
        case Keys.A: return shift ? "A" : "a"; 
        case Keys.B: return shift ? "B" : "b"; 
        case Keys.C: return shift ? "C" : "c"; 
        case Keys.D: return shift ? "D" : "d"; 
        case Keys.E: return shift ? "E" : "e"; 
        case Keys.F: return shift ? "F" : "f"; 
        case Keys.G: return shift ? "G" : "g"; 
        case Keys.H: return shift ? "H" : "h"; 
        case Keys.I: return shift ? "I" : "i"; 
        case Keys.J: return shift ? "J" : "j"; 
        case Keys.K: return shift ? "K" : "k"; 
        case Keys.L: return shift ? "L" : "l"; 
        case Keys.M: return shift ? "M" : "m"; 
        case Keys.N: return shift ? "N" : "n"; 
        case Keys.O: return shift ? "O" : "o"; 
        case Keys.P: return shift ? "P" : "p"; 
        case Keys.Q: return shift ? "Q" : "q"; 
        case Keys.R: return shift ? "R" : "r"; 
        case Keys.S: return shift ? "S" : "s"; 
        case Keys.T: return shift ? "T" : "t"; 
        case Keys.U: return shift ? "U" : "u"; 
        case Keys.V: return shift ? "V" : "v"; 
        case Keys.W: return shift ? "W" : "w"; 
        case Keys.X: return shift ? "X" : "x"; 
        case Keys.Y: return shift ? "Y" : "y"; 
        case Keys.Z: return shift ? "Z" : "z"; 

        // Oem 
        case Keys.OemOpenBrackets: return shift ? "{" : "["; 
        case Keys.OemCloseBrackets: return shift ? "}" : "]"; 
        case Keys.OemComma: return shift ? "<" : ","; 
        case Keys.OemPeriod: return shift ? ">" : "."; 
        case Keys.OemMinus: return shift ? "_" : "-"; 
        case Keys.OemPlus: return shift ? "+" : "="; 
        case Keys.OemQuestion: return shift ? "?" : "/"; 
        case Keys.OemSemicolon: return shift ? ":" : ";"; 
        case Keys.OemQuotes: return shift ? "\"" : "'";
        case Keys.OemPipe: return shift ? "|" : "\\";
        case Keys.OemTilde: return shift ? "~" : "`"; 
    } 

    return string.Empty; 
}
```

EDIT:
So I tried this in the update procedure of XNA.

```
var newkbState = Keyboard.GetState();
Keys[] pressedKeys = newkbState.GetPressedKeys();
newInput = null;

if (newkbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftShift) || newkbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.RightShift))
{
    shiftNew = true;
}
else
{
    shiftNew = false;
}

for (int count = 0; count < pressedKeys.Length; count++)
{
    newInput += ConvertKeyToChar(pressedKeys[count], shiftNew) ;
}

if (newInput != oldInput)
{
    text2 += newInput;
}
oldInput = newInput;
```

Now my problem is that, if I hold S, and pressed O, it'll type SOSS. Is there anyway i can stop this from happening?

EDIT2:
               var newkbState = Keyboard.GetState();
               newkbState = GetKeysPressedBetween(oldkbState, newkbState);
               Keys[] pressedKeys;
               pressedKeys = newkbState.GetPressedKeys();

```
            if (newkbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftShift) ||       newkbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.RightShift))
            {
                shiftNew = true;
            }
            else
            {
                shiftNew = false;
            }

            newInput = "";

            for (int count = 0; count < pressedKeys.Length; count++)
            {
                newInput += ConvertKeyToChar(pressedKeys[count], shiftNew);

            }

           if ((newInput != oldInput) && (newkbState != oldkbState))
            {
            text2 += newInput;
            }
           oldInput = newInput;
            oldkbState = newkbState;
```

Alright so, I tried the answerer's code and now I'm having problems. What's happening is:
1. Just tapping the letter "a" once outputs 3 a's.
2. When two buttons are pressed, a and b, the first problem happens and abababababab just keeps repeating as i hold onto it. If I fix the first problem, I'm not sure if the second would fix.

Comment: This Microsoft website has an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203902.aspx. Check the `UpdateInput()` method.

Comment: Multiple keys can be pressed at once, which is why `GetPressedKeys` returns an array. How do you expect to handle that?

Comment: I did something, its in the edit.  I still have a problem though.

Comment: Have you tried using [Keyboard.getState().getPressedKeys()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.keyboardstate.getpressedkeys.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exactly address the main question, but it solves a basic issue with your code.

```
KeyboardState GetKeysPressedBetween(KeyboardState first, KeyboardState second)
{
    KeyboardState pressed = new KeyboardState();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        FieldInfo currentStateI = typeof(KeyboardState).GetField("currentState" + i, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        uint firstCurrentStateI = (uint)currentStateI.GetValue(first);
        uint secondCurrentStateI = (uint)currentStateI.GetValue(second);
        currentStateI.SetValueDirect(__makeref(pressed), ~firstCurrentStateI & secondCurrentStateI);
    }
    return pressed;
}
```

This function will get you a `KeyboardState` that indicates which keys were pressed between two frames. You need something like this to be able to have any sensible ability to type.

Basically what you need to do is store the `KeyboardState` from the last frame, and use it to compare with the current frame, so you only type a key the first frame after it's pressed.

You should be able to use this with your existing code from the edit.

Comment: I'm using XNA and it says "FieldInfo" and "Binding Flags" does not exist in the current context. I've never used those before so is there something I have to add? And does that work for multiple keys being pressed at the same time, or just one?

Comment: I believe you'll need `using System.Reflection;`, and it will pick up multiple keys, but it won't know in what order they were pressed. If they were pressed within 1/30th of a second, it won't be too noticeable anyway.

Comment: Ugh, I ran across yet another problem. Is there anyway I could contact you easier to get some help? This is really frustruating me D:. I'll make another edit with my problem.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are overwriting `newkbState` with the 'delta' state. This causes the wrong state to be set to `oldkbState`. You should probably make a separate variable for it instead.